# Flutter how to make item of ListView after scrolling alway in the Center of screen

Tags: android, listview, flutter, center

I'm struggling with centering widget inside listView.

In my application I have an horizontal `ListView` which holds 20 to 30 items. Each item has a width equal to width of the screen. I want that each item must remain in the center of screen after scrolling.

How can I achieve this? Thank you very much!

This is my listView image  :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is the package you want : [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider)

Comment: Thanks bro! but the package just allow me scroll one by one, I want to scroll more, it depend on speed of scroll.

Comment: Ok, then try this one : [flutter_mobile_carousel](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mobile_carousel)